# Explain to me what is this exercise about?

Tags: amplifier, differential

A differential amplifier is fed in a balanced way through the source resistances Rs which are in series with each of the bases.If there exists a mismatch ΔRs between two source resistances draw the amplifier scheme and calculate the approximated value of the input offset voltage.

I came accross this exercise and it seems like a riddle.Can you explain me what is this about,or show me the scheme? I can then calculate the input offset voltage myself..

Comment: I think you should be able to take a shot at this and make a diagram that can be critiqued. At least shwo some effort in trying to understand this. The words are all there btw.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a standard differential amplifier (diff pair) with series resistors in between the input and the transistor base.  The idea is that the base current times the mismatch in the series resistors will give you a differential voltage offset.